# SQL Improvement in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables (`Order, OrderStatus`) as below. `Order.OrderCode` and `OrderStatus.Status` are indexed.

`Order` table:

```
Id(PK),OrderCode
1,"AA-001"
2,"AA-001"
3,"AA-002"
4,"AA-002"
5,"AA-003"
```

`OrderStatus` table:

```
Id(PK),OrderId(FK),Status,CreatedAt
1,1,"Open",2021-05-01 13:00:00
2,1,"Close",2021-05-01 13:05:00
3,2,"Open",2021-05-01 13:10:01
4,3,"Open",2021-05-01 13:10:02
5,3,"Close",2021-05-01 13:11:00
6,4,"Open",2021-05-01 13:11:01
7,4,"Close",2021-05-01 13:11:05
8,5,"Open",2021-05-01 13:12:00
```

I have a query to return the total `Order` count for any `OrderCode` group which has a latest `Open` status.

For example `OrderCode AA-001` and `OrderCode AA-003` have `Order` (ID:2,5) who have latest `Open` status. The query result would be `3`.

```
OrderCode,Count
"AA-001",2
"AA-003",1
```

This is the query I have now. The inner query in the `IN` condition is basically to find `Order` record whose latest `Status` is `Open`. Is there any other way to improve this query? Thanks.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM Order as ord
WHERE ord.OrderCode in (
   SELECT distinct(or.OrderCode)
   from Order as or
   left JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (OrderId) *
      FROM OrderStatus
      ORDER BY OrderId, CreatedAt DESC
   ) orsts ON orsts.OrderId = or.Id
   where orsts.Status = 'Open'
)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `count(1)` is actually slower than `count(*)` if you expected that to do some magic performance improvement ( `count(1)` is never faster than `count(*)` in any database). Also: `distinct` is not a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing a column in parentheses won't change anything

Comment: Do you want a result per order_code? So `AA-001, 2` and `AA-002, 2`? Or a total count of all orders that have at least one "latest" status in `open`? Please **[edit]** your question and add the expected result based on your sample data.

Comment: Latter case. I want a total count of all orders that have at least one latest status as Open.

Comment: I don't understand why `AA-001` has a count of 2. The latest status of order_id = 1 is `Close` not `Open`. Only for order_id = 2 the latest status is `Open`

Comment: `AA-001` has count of 2 because one of its Order (ID:2) is Open. Even though Order.ID:1 has status Close, I need it to be part of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be *describing*:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderCode)
FROM Order o JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT ON (os.OrderId) *
      FROM OrderStatus os
      ORDER BY os.OrderId, os.CreatedAt DESC
     ) orsts
     ON orsts.OrderId = o.Id
WHERE orsts.Status = 'Open';
```

For performance, you want an index on `OrderStatus(OrderId, CreatedAt DESC)`.